# advanced search - mailing fields not present

Tags: civimail, advanced-search

I am having a "moment". On one of my civicrms when I use the advanced search I can search mailings. On one of my other civicrm installations the mailings are not available to be searched - the accordian is short of the "mailings" tab. I'm assuming it is somewhere in the configuration but I cannot find it, nor can I find it in the user guide.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that without these fields being present you can get some very weird behaviour. e.g. Mailing report » Bounces » Advanced Search link might show 100 contacts. Then try to use those contacts, e.g. add them to a group, and you'll  notice the number in the group is not 100 but *all your contacts*. Ahem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look in civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

This is a bit counter-intuitive since the first place most would look is under Search Preferences - but it lives under Display Preferences as it is about what displays on the search screen. hth